# iOS RestKit Blocks

Tags: ios, restkit, block

I´m trying to wait for the response using Restkit with Blocks.

Example:

```
NSArray *myArray = ["RESULT OF REST-REQUEST"];

// Working with the array here.
```

One of my Block-requests:

```
- (UIImage*)getPhotoWithID:(NSString*)photoID style:(NSString*)style authToken:(NSString*)authToken {
__block UIImage *image;
NSDictionary *parameter = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"auth_token", authToken, nil];
RKURL *url = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"urlBase" resourcePath:@"resourcePath" queryParameters:parameter];
NSLog(@"%@", [url absoluteString]);
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:[url absoluteString] usingBlock:^(RKRequest *request) {
    request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [response bodyAsString]); 
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:[response body]];
    };
}];
return image;
}
```

Comment: the Array will be null because the method reaches the end before the response arrived... How can i "wait" for the response. I thought that that would work with blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return anything in this method since the getting of the image will be asynchronous - it must be `-(void)`.

So, what do you do? You should put the action calling this method inside the response block. Be wary of [retain cycles](http://borkwarellc.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/block-retain-cycles/) in the block.

```
__block MyObject *selfRef = self;

[[RKClient sharedClient] get:[url absoluteString] usingBlock:^(RKRequest *request) {
    request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {

         NSLog(@"Response: %@", [response bodyAsString]); 

         image = [UIImage imageWithData:[response body]];

         [selfRef doSomethingWithImage:image];

    };
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above won't work with ARC turned on (XCode default since iOS 5.0). __block variables are no longer exempted from auto-retain under ARC. Use __weak instead of __block in iOS 5.0 and above to break the retain cycle.